# hide the toggle bar for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code for toggle menu, when i click on toggle the side menu gets hidden and when i click on toggle again it appears. but i want a slight change in it, currently when the page is loaded for the first time, the side menu appears by default and when i click on toggle then it disappears i want that for the first time when the page is loaded the side menu should be hidden and when i click on toggle then it should appear. can anyone please tell how to do so

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

       <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">toggle</a>
   </div>
   <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
       $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        });
    </script>
```

css used for the entire toggle

```
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can you toggle it then when it is hidden?

Comment: Just apply `display: none` for `#wrapper` by css

Comment: @Justinas if i am adding display: none to wrapper then toggle button is also hidding, and i am not able to click on it

Comment: @samuel check my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger the click event after binding it:

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
}).click();  //click triggered....
```

Comment: One question since the anchor is within the wrapper will this not hide the toggle link?

Comment: @Pekka: OP is not toggling display property, he is toggling the class. so it is quite possible that there is some css defined that do the job of hiding `#sidebar-wrapper` element.

Comment: `first time when the page is loaded the side menu should be hidden and when i click on toggle then it should appear` i think this one explains that he wants to toggle display property.

Comment: @Pekka: This whole toggling part will not work if OP would have used display none. there is something else being used.

Comment: @Milind Anantwar your method is hiding the side menu when the page loads for the first time, but it is showing the entire sliding effect that hides the side bar, i want that for the first time only the toggle link should be visible and nothing else

Comment: @samuel: well in that case you need to add class `toggled` in wrapper element html in beginning only. like this `<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default toggled" id="menu-toggle">toggle</a>`

Comment: @Milind Anantwar It is still displaying the sliding effect, i have updated the post and have also added the css that is being used, can u plz go thru it once

Comment: @Milind Anantwar like in ur given fiddle for the first time the black side bar is hidden i want the same, but in my original script this is not happening

Comment: @samuel: can you reproduce that in fiddle??

Answer (score 1):

You should make `display:none` in `sidebar-wrapper` div

```
#sidebar-wrapper{
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: the toggle link is within the wrapper if you hide the wrapper including the toggle link how can you toggle it?

Comment: @Pekka it is hidding the entire sidebar, i have updated the post also, can u plz have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You missed `$("#wrapper").hide();` parameter

You can use it

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
        </ul>
   </div> 
</div>
<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">toggle menu</a>

<script>
 $("#wrapper").hide();
 $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#wrapper").toggle();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: the toggle link is visible only for the first time, for more than one instance it gets hidden , i have updated the post also, can u plz have a look at it

Answer (score -1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xgop31hb/)

```
$("#wrapper").hide();
$("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggle();
});
```

I remove the `toggle` anchor inside the wrapper so during hidding of wrapper the toggle link is still available to click then i use `.toggle()`

Comment: @samuel what do you want to happened?remove the line `$("#wrapper").hide();` and go on with how you hide it for the first time